# Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject in c# returns E_INVALIDARG error message

Tags: c#, .net, com

I try to create a program that consumes plugins with COM-interface.

I implement IClassFactory interface to create instances of plugin. The CreateInstance-Method is implemented this way:

```
public int CreateInstance(IntPtr pUnkOuter, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TestClassFactory CreateInstance");
        ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (pUnkOuter != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // The pUnkOuter parameter was non-NULL and the object does 
            // not support aggregation.
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(ComNative.CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION);
        }

        if (riid == new Guid(ManagerGuids.ClassId)
            || riid == new Guid(ComNative.IID_IDispatch)
            || riid == new Guid(ComNative.IID_IUnknown))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Pre GetComInterfaceForObject");
            // Create the instance of the .NET object
            // The container has to be passed as property and not by constructor injection.
            // This is because COM (de-)registration needs a constructor without parameters.
            ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(new NetPlugin(), typeof(INetPlugin));

            MessageBox.Show("Post GetComInterfaceForObject");
        }
        else
        {
            // The object that ppvObject points to does not support the 
            // interface identified by riid.
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(ComNative.E_NOINTERFACE);
        }

        return WinError.S_OK;
    }
```

The call of `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(new NetPlugin(), typeof(INetPlugin));` returns invalid argument error (E_INVALIDARG).

The arguments of the method:

NetPlugin:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid(ManagerGuids.ClassId)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class NetPlugin : INetPlugin
{
    public NetPlugin()
        {

        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x1)]
        public String LastParameters
        {
            get { return ""; }
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x2)]
        public String Vendor
        {
            get { return "Company"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x3)]
        public String Description
        {
            get { return "Test plugin written in .NET"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x4)]
        public String Version
        {
            get { return "1.0"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x5)]
        public String Category
        {
            get { return "Void"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x6)]
        public String MenuEntry
        {
            get { return "NetPlugin"; }
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x7)]
        public String MessageString
        {
            get { return "NetPlugin"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x8)]
        public String TooltipText
        {
            get { return "Tooltip NetPlugin"; }
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0x9)]
        public String FriendlyName
        {
            get { return "NetPlugin FFFFF Friendly"; }
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0xa)]
        public String BitmapResourceSmall
        {
            get { return "BitmapResourceSmall.bmp"; }
            set { }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0xb)]
        public String BitmapResourceLarge
        {
            get { return "BitmapResourceLarge.bmp"; }
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0xc)]
        public String Key
        {
            get { return ""; } // must be empty 
            set { }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0xd)]
        public String Reserved
        {
            get { return "Void"; }
            set { }
        }



        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DispIdAttribute(0xe)]
        public Int32 Run()
        {
            //-- Return scode
            return 0;
        }
}
```

INetPlugin:

```
[Guid(ManagerGuids.InterfaceId), ComVisible(true)]
interface INetPlugin
{
    [DispId(0x1)]
    String LastParameters { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x2)]
    String Vendor { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x3)]
    String Description {get; set; }

    [DispId(0x4)]
    String Version { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x5)]
    String Category { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x6)]
    String MenuEntry { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x7)]
    String MessageString { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x8)]
    String TooltipText { get; set; }

    [DispId(0x9)]
    String FriendlyName { get; set; }

    [DispId(0xa)]
    String BitmapResourceSmall { get; set; }

    [DispId(0xb)]
    String BitmapResourceLarge { get; set; }

    [DispId(0xc)]
    String Key { get; set; }

    [DispId(0xd)]
    String Reserved { get; set; }

    [DispId(0xe)]
    Int32 Run();
}
```

The NetPlugin is registred this way:

```
RegistrationServices rs = new RegistrationServices();
bool b = rs.RegisterAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);

if (!b)
    return 998;

String exePath = new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
                Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{" + ManagerGuids.ClassId + @"}\LocalServer32", "", exePath);
```

The INetPlugin is registred this way:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\InterfaceGUID]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\InterfaceGUID\ProxyStubClsid32]
@="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\InterfaceGUID\TypeLib]
@="{228a33a4-193a-4d6e-93ee-6aba49be9488}"
"Version"="1.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\InterfaceGUID]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\InterfaceGUID\ProxyStubClsid32]
@="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\InterfaceGUID\TypeLib]
@="{228a33a4-193a-4d6e-93ee-6aba49be9488}"
"Version"="1.0"
```

I'll be very thankful for any help!

Comment: This code cannot compile, the interface is not *public*.  The .reg file is pretty bizarre.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).